# How to exclude a graphics object for automatic plotrange calculation

Tags: graphics

In `Graphics`, I would like the `PlotRange` to be calculated automatically, but I would like to exclude some graphics objects (in my case: auxiliary circles) from that `PlotRange` calculation.

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be the case that objects plotted with `Prolog` and `Epilog` are not included in the `PlotRange` calculation (though I could not find this confirmed in the documentation).